# How to Create Charts in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can statistical data be shown in a chart format using the Razor Chart Helper of MVC ?

Answer (score 3):

When you want to display your data in graphical form, you can use Chart helper. The Chart helper can render an image that displays data in a variety of chart types.

You can create a view having razor code for chart as follows(lets say its MyChart.cshtml).

Bar chart from Array with theam

```
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Green)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "ChartTitle",
            xValue: new[] {  "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .Write();
}
```

Pie chart from Array

```
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Green)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "ChartTitle",
            chartType: "Pie",
            xValue: new[] {  "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .Write();
}
```

Pie chart from Array with theam

```
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "ChartTitle",
            chartType: "Pie",
            xValue: new[] {  "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .Write();
}
```

Bar Chart Using DB Query

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("DBName");
    var data = db.Query("SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Table");
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .DataBindTable(dataSource: data, xField: "Col1")
        .Write();
}
```

You can use these chart views/PartialView where ever required as a src of image.

ex.

```
<html>
    <body>
         <img src="MyChart.cshtml" />
         <!-- or <img src='@Url.Action("Controler","ActionNameOfChartRenderingView")' />-->
    <body>
<html>
```

Chart Theams

> **Vanilla**       Displays red    columns on a white background.
>
> **Blue**         Displays blue   columns on a blue gradient background.
>
> **Green**         Displays blue   columns on a green gradient background.
>
> **Yellow**        Displays orange columns on a yellow gradient background.
>
> **Vanilla3D**     Displays 3-D red columns on a white background.

SeriesChartType enumeration supports the following:

1. Area
2. Bar
3. BoxPlot
4. Bubble
5. Candlestick
6. Column
7. Doughnut
8. ErrorBar
9. FastLine
10. FastPoint
11. Funnel
12. Kagi
13. Line
14. Pie
15. Point
16. PointAndFigure
17. Polar
18. Pyramid
19. Radar
20. Range
21. RangeBar
22. RangeColumn
23. Renko
24. Spline
25. SplineArea
26. SplineRange
27. StackedArea
28. StackedArea100
29. StackedBar
30. StackedBar100
31. StackedColumn
32. StackedColumn100
33. StepLine
34. Stock
35. ThreeLineBreak

This is the list of names that you can pass, as strings, to the Chart helper in a Razor page.

This is Helper

```
namespace System.Web.Helpers
{
    public class Chart
    {
        public Chart(int width, int height, string template = null, string templatePath = null);
        public string FileName { get; }
        public int Height { get; }
        public int Width { get; }
        public Chart AddLegend(string title = null, string name = null);
        public Chart AddSeries(string name = null, string chartType = "Column", string chartArea = null, string axisLabel = null, string legend = null, int markerStep = 1, IEnumerable xValue = null, string xField = null, IEnumerable yValues = null, string yFields = null);
        public Chart AddTitle(string text = null, string name = null);
        public Chart DataBindCrossTable(IEnumerable dataSource, string groupByField, string xField, string yFields, string otherFields = null, string pointSortOrder = "Ascending");
        public Chart DataBindTable(IEnumerable dataSource, string xField = null);
        public byte[] GetBytes(string format = "jpeg");
        public static Chart GetFromCache(string key);
        public Chart Save(string path, string format = "jpeg");
        public string SaveToCache(string key = null, int minutesToCache = 20, bool slidingExpiration = true);
        public Chart SaveXml(string path);
        public Chart SetXAxis(string title = "", double min = 0, double max = 0.0 / 0.0);
        public Chart SetYAxis(string title = "", double min = 0, double max = 0.0 / 0.0);
        public WebImage ToWebImage(string format = "jpeg");
        public Chart Write(string format = "jpeg");
        public static Chart WriteFromCache(string key, string format = "jpeg");
    }
}
```

example ...

Controler

```
namespace MVC3ChartTest.Controllers
{
    public class ChartsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult BasicChart()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult BasicChartWithMasterPage() 
        { 
            return View(); 
        }
    }
}
```

non-strongly-typed view

```
@model dynamic
@{
    View.Title = "BasicChart";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
    <h2>Basic Chart</h2>
<p>
    @{
        var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Staff Mobility")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] {  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Api", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"}, 
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3","4","9","2","5"}
            ) 
        .Write();
    }
</p>
```

BasicChartWithMasterPage

```
@model dynamic
@{
    View.Title = "BasicChartWithMasterPage";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
    <h2>BasicChartWithMasterPage</h2>
    <p><img src="BasicChart" /> </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Example 2

Model

```
//other omitted...
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Helpers;
namespace MVC3ChartTest.Models
{
    internal class PieChartData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Category_Sales_for_1997[] Data { get; set; }
    }
    public class NorthModel
    {
        NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();
        List<Category_Sales_for_1997> pieData;
        public Chart PieChart
        {
            get
            {
                return BuildServerPieChart();
            }
        }
        public NorthModel()
        {
            pieData = db.Category_Sales_for_1997.ToList<Category_Sales_for_1997>();
        }
//other omitted...
```

Functions to return chart

```
private Chart BuildServerPieChart()
{
    var data = new PieChartData
    {
        Title = "Total: " + (from y in pieData select y.CategorySales).Sum().ToString(),
        Data = (from x in pieData orderby x.CategoryName descending select x).ToArray(),
    };
    return BindChartData(data);
}
private Chart BindChartData(PieChartData data)
{
    Chart chart = new Chart(
        width: 400, 
        height: 300,
        template: ChartTheme.Green);
    chart.AddTitle(data.Title);
    chart.AddLegend(title: "Lengend Title", name: null);
    ArrayList x_ValueArray = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList y_ValuesArray = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Data.Length; i++)
    {
        x_ValueArray.Add(data.Data[i].CategoryName);
        y_ValuesArray.Add(data.Data[i].CategorySales);
    }
    chart.AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            chartType: "Pie",
            axisLabel: "Name",
            xValue: x_ValueArray,
            yValues: y_ValuesArray);
    return chart;
}
```

Controller Action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    NorthModel model = new NorthModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model MVC3ChartTest.Models.NorthModel
@{
    View.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
    <h2>Index</h2>
    <div>
    @{Model.PieChart.Write();}
    </div>
```